Meaning of AlphaGeometry’s `eqangle` geometric property
This a basic question about Google DeepMind AlphaGeometry source code. This program uses a neural language model + a symbolic deduction engine to solve geometry problem. In particular, the symbolic deduction engine seems to be supplied by a rules.txt file, where it's interesting/fun to recognize some basic geometrical facts. See e.g. the first line:
perp A B C D, perp C D E F, ncoll A B E => para A B E F

which I guess means:

“if $(AB) \perp (CD)$ and $(CD) \perp (EF)$, then $(AB) // (EF)$”

(with a non-collinearity condition for $A,B,E$ to exclude line equality $(AB)=(EF)$)
The rules files is described in the README as being the “Deduction rules for DD”, where DD stands for Deductive Database, implemented in dd.py.
I easily get the meaning of some keywords:

perp A B C D: let $(AB) \perp (CD)$
midp M A B: let $M$ be the midpoint of the $[A,B]$ segmet

However, I don't understand the eqangle keyword which appears e.g. in the following rules:
eqangle A B P Q C D P Q => para A B C D
cyclic A B P Q => eqangle P A P B Q A Q B
circle O A B C, eqangle A X A B C A C B => perp O A A X
circle O A B C, midp M B C => eqangle A B A C O B O M

The name suggests that it may be about angle equality. However, I'm used to define angles with 3 points, so this would make an angle equality directive with 2×3=6 points, whereas eqangle takes 8 points as arguments.

In the end, the meaning of the eqangle keyword could be infered from the README where there a console output of running AlphaGeometry, e.g. with the following line:
004. EC ⟂ EB [06] & CD ⟂ AB [01] ⇒  ∠(EC-BA) = ∠(EB-CD) [07]

so it means angles are defined not by three points, but by the intersection of 2 lines, so indeed 4 points.
Thus, among the statements I quoted:
eqangle A B P Q C D P Q => para A B C D

is the reciprocal of the equality of the Corresponding angles
while
cyclic A B P Q => eqangle P A P B Q A Q B
circle O A B C, midp M B C => eqangle A B A C O B O M

are about the Inscribed and Central angle theorem. Interestingly, instead of storing that the Central angle is twice the Inscribed angle, the rules speaks of the “half central angle” by placing a midpoint $M$ on the chord $BC$.
